# How to display full structure hash while running Perl debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging

While using perl in debugging mode if the structure of the hash variable (`x %h`) is too big to display on the screen, the how we can see the full structure of hash.

Is there any way to redirect the output of `x %h` to some file ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a [post on perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=983496) by *morgon* that explains how to do this. Here's the core part (emphasis/markdown mine).

> First set up a pager like this: `o pager=">my_file"` Then pipe the
>   x-command through the pager like this: `|x $huge_reference`
>
> That's it - "my_file" now contains the dump for you to inspect.
>
> You can even set up a pager as `">>my_file"` for appending.

Comment: FYI, I googled _perl debugger output to file_ and it was the first hit.